# "no step-definition method match" error when using Karate API forEach method

Tags: karate

I'm trying to use the forEach method in one of my feature files, but I keep getting this error:
"no step-definition method match found for: forEach..."

I even tried to use the example from the Karate [documentation](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/2ca51aca126d691d87c09f3b476cbbaef58881ca/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/js-arrays.feature#L48) but it still doesnt work.

Here is my runner:

```java
import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate;
import com.intuit.karate.KarateOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Karate.class)
@KarateOptions(features = "classpath:com/kenshoo/apitests/testForEach.feature")
public class ApiTestsRunner {

}
```

And here is my feature file:

```
Feature: Test forEach

  Scenario: karate forEach operation on lists
    * def res = []
    * def fun = function(x){ karate.appendTo(res, x * x) }
    * def list = [1, 2, 3]
    * forEach(list, fun)
    * match res == [1, 4, 9]
```

And this is the error i'm getting:

```
testForEach.feature:7 - no step-definition method match found for: forEach(list, fun)
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: testForEach.feature:7 - no step-definition method match found for: forEach(list, fun)
    at ✽.* forEach(list, fun) (testForEach.feature:7)
```

Karate API version - 0.9.3

Answer (score 5):

I reproduced your error with version 0.9.3.  Updating to version 0.9.4 will fix the issue.

In 0.9.4 the 'eval' keyword becomes optional.  This is why you are getting the 'no step-definition...' error.

See the release notes here:
https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases

---

It is a shame that the author spends more time giving people the middle finger and saying "RTFM" rather than actually being helpful.  I guess some people forget the challenges of learning a new language, especially for novice developers.  @EB123... you are only "missing" the fact that the answer presented by Mr. Thomas was written out of arrogance rather than humility.

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs carefully. It should be `karate.forEach(list, fun)` *and* the version that supports this syntax. If you are still stuck, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I've tried with Karate.forEach as well but I get the same error. And I went over the documentation, didnt find anything else, is there something I'm missing?
I guess I'll submit an issue. Thanks!

Comment: @EB123 you are definitely missing something. so as I said - follow those instructions in the link, all the best :)

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but I went over it again and again and just can't understand what is it that i'm missing.
Any chance you can point me at what i'm doing wrong? Do you prefer i'll open an issue?

Comment: @EB123 I have nothing more to add :)